# notification in saas application over azure

Tags: azure, notifications, message-queue, saas

We are working on a SaaS based application (built over azure). In this application Web server and App server is shared among all tenants but their database are separate (Sql Azure).

Now there is a need to implement notification service which can generate notifications based on events subscriptions. System can generate different kind of event (like account locked and many other) and user can configure notification rule on these events. Notification can be in the form of email and sms.

We are planning to implement a queue for events. Event notifier will push an even on this queue. Notification engine will subscribe to this queue. Whenever it receive a new event, it will check if there is a notification rule configured on this type of event or not. If yes, it will create a notification, which will result into emails/sms. These emails/sms can be stored in database or pushed to another queue. A different background process (worker role) can process these emails.

Here are my queries.

- Should we keep one single queue (for events) for all tenants or create separate queue for different tenants. If we keep a single queue, we can a shared subscriber service which can subscribe to this queue. We can easily scale in-out this machine.
- Since we have different databases for each tenant, we can store their emails to their respective databases and using some service, we can pool database and send email after defined interval. But I am not sure how will we share the subscriber code in this case.
- We can store mails in a nosql database (like table storage in azure). A subscriber (window service/worker role) can pool this table and send mails after defined interval. Again, scaling can a challenge here too.
- We can store emails in queue (RabbitMQ for instance). A worker role can subscribe to this queue. Scaling of worker role should not be any issue in case we keep a single queue for all tenant.

Please provide your inputs on these points.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate queues not by tenants but by function. So that queue handlers are specific for the type of a message that they are processing.

IE: order processing queue, an account setup queue, and etc.

Creating queues by tenant is a /headache/ to manage when you want to scale based on them and you want to presumably sync/add/remove them as customers come and leave. So, I would avoid this scenario

Ultimately, scaling based on multiple queues will be harder without auto-scaling services such as CloudMonix (a commercial product I help built)

HTH